# fsck doesn't write changes

Tags: filesystems, fsck, fat32

I'm trying to repair a SD card with *FAT,* but `fsck` doesn't write changes — even the magic `-w` option doesn't help

```
$ sudo fsck.fat -aw /dev/sda1 
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Free cluster summary wrong (240886 vs. really 241296)
  Auto-correcting.
Performing changes.
/dev/sda1: 3471 files, 240319/481615 clusters
```

Looks like repaired ↑. But every restart of *fsck*, it reports the same problems, and pretends that it fixes them with the same text.

Here's the verbose variant

```
$ sudo fsck.fat -awv /dev/sda1 
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
      4096 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   1926656 bytes per FAT (= 3763 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 3869696 (sector 7558)
    481615 data clusters (1972695040 bytes)
62 sectors/track, 61 heads
      2048 hidden sectors
   3860480 sectors total
Reclaiming unconnected clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
Free cluster summary wrong (240886 vs. really 241296)
  Auto-correcting.
Performing changes.
/dev/sda1: 3471 files, 240319/481615 clusters
```

Comment: The card is damaged. Replace it. Btw, Android phone also accept ext2fs at least.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro but I still can mount it in the PC just fine, so it works, doesn't it? Btw, thank you for the hint about ext2, I'll try it the next time.

Comment: Working is not the same as not being damaged; the symptoms you describe is not a good sign. I would throw away the card. Do not use it for anything important.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro but if it is damaged, shouldn't I see in the `fsck` output some kind of IO errors?

Comment: Not necessarily, unfortunately, and I have seen those behaviour in different technologies, from memory cards, to hard disks, and god knows what else...the definition of a malfunction is something behaving in an unpredictable way, we are actually lucky when it throws an error.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro you may post it as answer, turns out you were right. I just mounted the card, deleted files, remounted, and the files appeared there like if I didn't remove them. Another failed experiment I did: I tried creating ext2 there. `mkfs` reported the successful creation, but the `fdisk -l /dev/sda` still reports FAT, and after mount nothing seem to be changed.

Comment: I posted an answer detailing a bit more of ideas of the SD cards operation with Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact the card behaves erratically and in a unpredictable way , the same errors surface again and again is not a good sign, and is actually a sure symptom of damaged media. It got nothing to do with FAT problems.
I would discard the card, as it cannot be trusted. Unfortunately, the SD cards only last so much, and cards with extensive operations of writes have usually a shorter life.

Android also supports ext2fs filesystems. If you use the card exclusively in Linux, it might be an interesting alternative.

Be aware that whilst other Linux filesystems *might* be supported, it is not a good idea to use in SD cards transactional filesystems as ext3fs. The transactional support/writes on the filesystem will increase the wear and tear.

Answer (score 1):

this command lookes correct, but you have to involve that there is also a firmawre in your sdcard which would propaly block write processes (for example do to broken flash chip) and dont reporting that correct to the operating system.

I would suggest to check the card with a software like dd and md5sum for read-write failors on different systems/cardreaders and if there is only one suspicion about that it is not acting correctly replace it. Also i would suggest to not buy the cheapest cards...

regards